# Finding the median in java without sorting

Tags: java, median

I need to write a program in java to find the median of an array of three or more integers without sorting. I need some ideas. thanks

Comment: Out of interest, why would you not just sort it?

Comment: You want a [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) like [quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect).

Comment: @Jon Taylor Because it's homework

Comment: @pianoman If I had to guess, yes I would agree, however, there could be applications where sorts are impractical, for example time critical systems (especially if the array was very large)

Comment: @pianoman Why the snarky comments. Even if it is homework, why does that matter? It sounds like user just wants some kind of ideas to start and isn't asking for someone to program

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [Selection Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). You'll also find relevant information looking for [Median of Medians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Quick sort partitioning step with random pivots, without sorting it.

```
public class TestMedian {

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        int[] a = {1,9,-4,7,6,11,3,2,10}; 
        int median; 

        median = new Median().findMedian(a,0,a.length-1); 
        if(a.length%2 != 0) 
            System.out.print("the median is : "+a[median]); 
        else 
            System.out.print("the median is : "+(a[median] + a[median + 1])/2 ); 
    } 
    public int findMedian(int[] a,int left,int right){ 
        int index = 0; 
        int mid = (left+right)/2; 
        index = partition(a,left,right); 
        while( index != mid){ 
            if(index < mid) 
                index = partition(a,mid,right); 
            else index = partition(a,left,mid); 
        } 
        return index; 
    } 
    public int partition(int[] a,int i,int j ){ 
        int pivot = (i+j)/2; 
        int temp; 
        while(i <= j){ 
            while(a[i] < a[pivot]) 
                i++; 
            while(a[j] > a[pivot]) 
                j--; 
            if(i <= j){ 
                temp = a[i]; 
                a[i]=a[j]; 
                a[j] = temp; 
                i++;j--; 
            } 
        } 
        return pivot; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: On [ 3, 8, 10, 35, 54, 84, 101 ] messed up a little it returns 84 (as if searched equal sums of numbers on the left an on the right), but should return 35: median is 0.5 percentile - it should point to an element dividing array on two with 1/2 elements less than and 1/2 greater than it